# Can values_list() return the name instead of id?

Tags: python, django

I have two models like so:

```
class Budget(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Transaction(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(
        max_length=3,
        choices=[('inc', 'Income'), ('exp', 'Expense')],
        default='inc'
    )
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    description = models.TextField()
    added_by = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    objects = TransactionQuerySet.as_manager()
    budget = models.ForeignKey(Budget, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

...and I have a custom Manager method on my TransactionQuerySet:

```
class TransactionQuerySet(models.QuerySet):

    def categorize_budgets(self):
        return self.model.objects.values_list('budget').annotate(total=Sum('amount'))
```

I want to categorize expenses by budget and sum them up, and when I do:

```
>>> Transaction.objects.filter(added_by=user, type='exp').categorize_budgets()
<TransactionQuerySet [(1, Decimal('4'))]>
```

what it returns is, I suppose budget id). I want it to return budget name instead, is that possible? I have a workaround like this, but I'm wondering if the DB can do all the work in one go:

```
def get_expenses(self):
    expenses = Transaction.objects.filter(
        added_by=self.request.user, type='exp'
    ).categorize_budgets()
    mappings = {
        Budget.objects.get(id=k).name: v for k, v in expenses
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the usual Django related lookup i.e. `budget__name`:

```
class TransactionQuerySet(models.QuerySet):

    def categorize_budgets(self):
        return self.model.objects.values_list('budget__name').annotate(total=Sum('amount'))
```